# C# how to get a icon of a web

Tags: c#, html, wpf, web

I create a program when user can write in site URL and i want to display a ICON of his side in separate window. Is there any method to get the ICON form a site? Using C# with WPF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to request the favicon for the site which is generally on the root/favicon.ico, for instance, stackoverflow is

https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico

Answer (score -1):

No idea if thats what you want, but if you mean the Favicon of a website, you may just want to load the image into an image box from [www.DESTINATIONURL.TLD/favicon.ico/png/jpg](http://www.DESTINATIONURL.TLD/favicon.ico/png/jpg)

But if it's not important to make it dynamic at all, you should just download the favicon and put it as resource of your application ^^